# Insert cell in table row eclipse birt

Tags: birt

I can't seem to find a way to insert another cell in a row of my table in a Birt report in Eclipse, does anybody know how to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly sure which problem you are having but the solution should either be;

1 Insert a column in the table

- Select the table
- Right mouse click at top of column and insert a column to left or right

2.Insert a grid into an existing cell, without adding a column. (*Usually you do this when you want to have a label and an aggregation in the same header or footer cell*)

- From the Palette, drag and drop a 'Grid" element into the cell,
- set 'number of columns' to 2 and 'number of rows' to 1.
- put you other elements (i.e. label and aggregation) into the seperate cells of the grid in the single cell of the table.

Comment: This is definitely the answer, but often I have difficulty getting Eclipse to show the grid controls (I.e. show row/column handles that you right-click to insert new row/column before/after) - especially when I have nested grids where spacing is tight. There is an excellent technique to help with this - click on any cell and then press alt+up: this will select the parent element. It works on any visual element and alt+down works in reverse, which is very handy too.

Comment: Good tip. I wonder why it does not have this option in the tree view. It should be possible to right-click on the cell and have the option there.